# Fancy Attributes does not show selected option

Tags: commerce

I'm trying to use Fancy Attributes to display colour variations in my Drupal Commerce store. The colours, and associated descriptions display, and I can click on a colour to select that variation. My problem is that it does not change the display of the colour variation in any way to show which one is selected. This is especially important because I also have a size attribute that seems to reset the colour attribute if clicked after the colour is chosen.

Is there any way to, for example, make the description bold, or put a different border around the selected colour?

Answer (score 0):

OK... I think I answered my own question. I added the following to *commerce_fancy_attributes.css*:

```
.form-type-commerce-fancy-attributes-ajax .description .description-selected {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
}
```